# not able to install react-google-login

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks-testing-library, react-google-login

Trying to install "react-google-login" by using the command
 `npm install react-google-login`.
It gives the following error :

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: my-app@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16 || ^17" from react-google-login@5.2.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-google-login
npm ERR!   react-google-login@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\prajw\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\prajw\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-11T09_50_55_555Z-debug-0.log
```

Not able to understand what is going wrong.
Since the react has upgraded to version 18, there has been a lot of changes on how we used things previously.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why, but somehow it works.

run

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
```

Comment: had the same problem but after running this command I was able to install it

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately as the error message states, React 18 is not supported by "react-google-login".

While we wait for this, hopefully this helps.

```
npm uninstall react-google-login
npm install @leecheuk/react-google-login
```

[@leecheuk/react-google-login](https://github.com/leecheuk/react-google-login) is a fork of [anthonyjgrove/react-google-login](https://github.com/anthonyjgrove/react-google-login) and has plugin_name support & updated peerDependency for React 18.